# Deleting a File Using PHP

Tags: php, delete-file

How do I delete a file on the filesystem using PHP code?

```php
<?php
if (isset($_GET['remove']) && is_numeric($_GET['remove']))
{
//Delete here using $_GET['remove'] value
}

if (isset($_POST['Submit']) && $_POST['Submit'] == 'Remove Selected')
{
$id = array();
$id = $_POST['removeid'];
//print_r($id);
if (count($id) > 0)
{
 foreach ($id as $removeid)
 {
    //Delete here using $removeid value
 }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Take the time to see if your questions have already been asked (the list pops on the "Questions with similar titles" before you post), or just by doing a search on the stackoverflow page.  Check out the **Related** questions on the right side of the page...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use PHP's [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php).

Comment: Please elaborate your answer explaining how this should be used instead of posting a link to the manual...

Answer (score 0):

```
unlink ( string $filename [, resource $context ] )
```

get more details at: [php.net manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)